# Show that $(\Bbb{N}, \ast)$ is not a subgroup of $(\Bbb{Z},\ast).$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

> Let $\ast$ defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ by $a\ast b=a+b-1$  $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that $(\mathbb{N},\ast)$ is not a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z},\ast)$,where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers.

I showed it but I want to know whether it is correct or not?

Firstly I found inverse of element $b \in \mathbb{N}$ and then I found $ab^{-1}$ which is $a-b+1$ but it isn't $\in \mathbb{N}$ then $ab^{-1}$ isn't 
$\in \mathbb{N}$ so then I think I proved it?

If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: What? I didn't get a-1

Comment: If I was writing a formal proof, I would say that the identity element of the group $(\mathbb{Z},*)$ is 1, and that $a^{-1}=2-a$, so no element of $\mathbb{N}$ greater than 1 has an inverse (in $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Ah i got it thank you but i want to know why this is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is hard to follow your line of reasoning. Is $a-b+1$ not in $\mathbb{N}$ for all choices of $a$ and $b$ or only some? To establish that a subset of a group is not a subgroup of that group, what is it exactly that you need to show?

To show that $(\mathbb{N}, *)$ is not a subgroup it suffices to show that
there exists an $a \in (\mathbb{N}, *)$ such that $a^{-1} \not \in (\mathbb{N}, *)$. And indeed $a^{-1} = 2-a$, which is not in $(\mathbb{N}, *)$ if $a \ge 2$ say $a=3.$

Comment: Please tell me since i got a-b+1 if i put some element such as a=1,b=5 then ab^-1=-3 so then,am I correct?

Comment: If you gave a specific example of $a,b$ such that $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ but $a*b^{-1} \not \in \mathbb{N}$ [and indeed $a=1$ and $b=5$ would work], and you made it clear that this is what you were doing, then that suffices as correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I hope all turns out well with your exam, if that is what you were asking for!

Comment: Thnak you for your advices which are very valuable for me

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track by proving that the inverse operation is not well defined, or not internal. It can be easier to take an element in particular that is in $\mathbb{N}$, but which doesn't have an inverse in $\mathbb{N}$. Do you know about such an element?

Comment: I think you are saying to use counter example isn't you?

Comment: Indeed, if you can take an element, that doesn't have an inverse in $(\mathbb{N}, \ast)$ you're done, because the definition of a group requires all elements to have an inverse.

Comment: I got it thanks but i want to know whether this is wrong or not?please tell me why if this is not good way

Answer (score 0):

To disprove that $(\mathbb{N}, *)$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}, *)$ you need to give a counterexample to one of the axioms. For example, every element in the group needs an inverse that is also in the group.

Let $3=a \in \mathbb{N}$. Now we have to look for the number $a^{-1} \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a*a^{-1} = 1$. Now we know that $a*a^{-1} = a + a^{-1} -1 = 1 \implies a^{-1} = -1$. This is a contradiction to our assumption that $a^{-1} \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $(\mathbb{N}, *)$ cannot be a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}, *)$.